# Save file in a new folder?

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking to make a program that will open a file and upon saving it, the program will save it into a new folder, leaving the original file unchanged.

However, none of the codes I've tried using have worked.

How do I make a new folder that will go into the FilePath of the loaded file?

How do I then save into that folder?

I tried this and got the error.. "False was not found or could not be accessed"

`Private Sub SaveChangesToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveChangesToolStripMenuItem1.Click
        newFilePath = FilePath + "\" + newFolderName + "Folder"
        Try
            Dim Writer As New PackageIO.Writer(newFilePath = orgFilePath + "\" + newFolderName, "Folder 1", PackageIO.Endian.Big)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newFilePath)`

I tried this code here and it seemed to be the closest to working, but said the file path wasn't valid; I'm assuming because it's including the file they selected, not just the folders involved.

`Private Sub SaveChangesToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveChangesToolStripMenuItem1.Click
        newFilePath = FilePath + "\" + newFolderName + "Folder"
        Try
            Dim Writer As New PackageIO.Writer(newFilePath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newFilePath)`

Comment: Show us the codes you've tried.

Comment: more specific please, what kind of file? txt? word? excel? and what have you tried btw?

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
Dim orgFilePath as String
Dim newFolderName as String
Dim newFilePath as String

'you will need to set the path of the original file and give a name for the new folder
newFilePath = orgFilePath + "\" + newFolderName

'creates new directory (folder)
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newFilePath)

'then put the code to save your file to the newFilePath variable
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried this and got the error.. "False was not found or could not be accessed"
`Private Sub SaveChangesToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveChangesToolStripMenuItem1.Click
        Try
            Dim Writer As New PackageIO.Writer(newFilePath = orgFilePath + "\" + newFolderName, "Folder 1", PackageIO.Endian.Big)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newFilePath)`

Comment: I tried this code here and it seemed to be the closest to working, but said the file path wasn't valid; I'm assuming because it's including the file they selected, not just the folders involved.
`Private Sub SaveChangesToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveChangesToolStripMenuItem1.Click
        newFilePath = FilePath + "\" + newFolderName + "Folder"
        Try
            Dim Writer As New PackageIO.Writer(newFilePath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newFilePath)`